# Pass style to parents child in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a react material-ui expansion panel now the collapse child of that panel is causing me issues so I need to set it's overflow to visible however I do not know how I can do that in react especially since this child is not a class I've defined but a child of the imported expansion panel.

I've tested in the console and I know which class needs to `overflow: 'visible'` style on it however I have no idea how to apply it.

Below is my HTML and css for basic structure but really the question is how can I apply it to the child component of the expansion panel

The HTML

```
 <ExpansionPanel
  className={classes.expansionPanelExpanded}
  >

  // the stuff inside the panel            
 </ExpansionPanel>
```

The CSS

```
const materialStyles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    container: {
      overflow: 'visible'
    },
    expansionPanelExpanded: {
      boxShadow: 'none',
      root: {
        overflow: 'visible',
        expansionPanelExpanded: {
          overflow: 'visible'
        },
      },

    },

  })
```

All the stuff inside expansionPanelExpanded is what I've tried to pass the `overflow: 'visible'` to it's child which in the console appears with the className as:

```
class='MuiCollapse-container-444 MuiCollapse-entered-445'
```

The Parent of this class is:

```
 class='MuiPaper-root-405 MuiPaper-elevation1-408 MuiExpansionPanel-root-402 WithStyles-ExpansionPanel--root-500 MuiExpansionPanel-expanded-403'
```

if I can set the `overflow: visible` style for this it would solve my problem.

Comment: Hello! You do would can make example?

Comment: If you will make example, write.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов I think OP is saying he is trying to pass the className `expansionPanelExpanded` as a prop so that he can style the child of the Expansion Panel. But the CSS is not able to locate that class name `expansionPanelExpanded`.

Comment: The Material-UI expanionPanel has a Collapse child which contains a container child. I need to change the overflow of that container to be visible. the expansionPanelExpanded styles apply to the panel but I can't figure out how to access the Collapse child of the expansion Panel.